# Посчитать количество компонент связности графа

Tags: c#, графы, dfs

Нужно посчитать количество компонент связности графа (метод connected в классе Graph) с помощью матрицы смежности, но он постоянно выводит цифру 2, как исправить?

```
  public class Edge
    {
        public Vertex From { get; set; }
        public Vertex To { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public Edge(Vertex from, Vertex to, int weight = 1)
        {
            From = from;
            To = to;
            Weight = weight;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"({From};{To})";
        }
    }
    public class Vertex
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public bool visited { get; set; }
        public Vertex prev;
        public Vertex(int number)
        {
            Number = number;
        }
 
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"({Number})";
        }
    }
    class Graph
    {
        List<Vertex> Vertexes = new List<Vertex>();
        List<Edge> Edges = new List<Edge>();
    
        public int VertexCount => Vertexes.Count;
        public int EdgeCount => Edges.Count;
 
        public void AddVertex(Vertex vertex)
        {
            Vertexes.Add(vertex);
        }
 
        public void AddEdge(Vertex from, Vertex to)
        {
            var edge = new Edge(from, to);
            Edges.Add(edge);
        }
 
        public int[,] GetMatrix()
        {
            var matrix = new int[Vertexes.Count, Vertexes.Count];
 
            foreach (var edge in Edges)
            {
                var row = edge.From.Number - 1;
                var column = edge.To.Number - 1;
 
                matrix[row, column] = edge.Weight;
            }
 
            return matrix;
        }
 
        public List<Vertex> GetVetexLists(Vertex vertex)
        {
            var result = new List<Vertex>();
 
            foreach (var edge in Edges)
            {
                if (edge.From == vertex)
                {
                    result.Add(edge.To);
                }
            }
 
            return result;
        }
 
 
 
       public void DFS(Vertex cur)
        {
            var list = new List<Vertex>
            {
                cur
            };
 
            cur.visited = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertex = list[i];
                foreach (var v in GetVetexLists(vertex))
                {
                    if (!v.visited)
                        DFS(v);
                }
            }
        }
        public int Connected()
        {
 
            int cnt = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (Vertex v in Vertexes)
                {
                    if (!v.visited)
                    {
                        DFS(v);
                        ++cnt;
                    }
 
                }
                return cnt;
            }
        }
       
        public bool Wave(Vertex start, Vertex finish)
        {
            var list = new List<Vertex>
            {
                start
            };
 
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var vertex = list[i];
                foreach (var v in GetVetexLists(vertex))
                {
                    if (!list.Contains(v))
                    {
                        list.Add(v);
                    }
                }
            }
 
            return list.Contains(finish);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите код в такой вид, чтобы можно было его просто скопировать в идею, запустить и увидеть вашу проблему.

Comment: Как вы это тестировали?

Comment: Нужен пример использования, где вы получаете некорректный результат.